# Compiled .elf file with Ceva v18 takes up a lot of resources

Tags: tensorflow-lite

Last question, I asked how to compile tflite in windows, and a friend gave me a solution.
Then, I set up Cygwin env to compile tflite ceva.
first, `$tensorflow: make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile target=ceva target_arch=cevabx1generate_micro_speech_project` ;
next, copy the tensorflow + third_party to ceva IDE.
last， set IDE include path and library path.
it work!
But, the result .elf file is 7.5MB, and convert to .bin file is 1.1MB.
From the document, the size of the compiled bin file is several hundred KB.
Why do I compile a bin file of 1.1MB?
In build folder, there some big object file:
all_ops_resolver.o is 590KB, memory_helpers.o is 462KB, micro_allocator.o is 1267KB, micro_interpreter.o is 1180KB, recording_micro_allocator.o is 1133KB, test_helpers.o is 1534KB.
How to adjust the compiled file to reduce the space occupied by bin file?
By default, Cygwin make windows exe file only 500+KB
`make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile test_micro_speech_test`

Is the CEVA compiler causing such a big gap?

Comment: I have already use -O3 in compile step, bin file always 1.1MB

Comment: HI, all. I have solved the whole problem. Compile option add -Oz, build option add --relax and --gc-sections. V18 IDE options are not added by default.